# User define key equivalents

Tags: macos, nsmenuitem, nsmenu

I would like to allow the user to create their own key equivalents.
Below is a snap of the prefs page in Google Voice as an example.
I'm stumped on how to record the shortcut in a field as shown below.
I've yet to find an example or any help on this.
I would really appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For recording the shortcuts I suggest you take a look at ShortcutRecorder, here's a fork with a much improved version on Github:

https://github.com/Kentzo/ShortcutRecorder